# Get values and append to a list to then append to another list

Tags: python

So I'm scrapping using BS4 and I want to get each line of values in a different list and then merge all these lists into a single list.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
team_values = []
teams_values = []
for team in team_rows:
    team_data = team.find_all("td")

    for data in team_data:
        if hasattr(data, 'attrs') and 'data-val' in data.attrs:
            #print("\t{}".format(data.attrs['data-val']))
            value = data.attrs['data-val']
            #print(value)
            team_values.append(value)
            #print(team_values)
teams_values.append(team_values)
```

But it is returning a single list of values, instead of a list of lists. Any help please?

Comment: Indentation. Add one level of indentation to your last line.

Comment: It still doesn't work, I tried. It simply returns a huge list of lists with all elements in each of these lists.

Comment: Please paste some sample input and the output you get (or expect) so that what you're asking is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is off on the last line and you'll need to reset `team_values` before entry into the second `for` loop

```
teams_values = []
for team in team_rows:
    team_data = team.find_all("td")

    team_values = []                 # reset here  
    for data in team_data:
        if hasattr(data, 'attrs') and 'data-val' in data.attrs:
            #print("\t{}".format(data.attrs['data-val']))
            value = data.attrs['data-val']
            #print(value)
            team_values.append(value)
            #print(team_values)
    teams_values.append(team_values)        # add indentation here
```

Comment: did you also reset `team_values`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
teams_values = []
for team in team_rows:
    team_values = []
    team_data = team.find_all("td")

    for data in team_data:
        if hasattr(data, 'attrs') and 'data-val' in data.attrs:
            #print("\t{}".format(data.attrs['data-val']))
            value = data.attrs['data-val']
            #print(value)
            team_values.append(value)
            #print(team_values)
    teams_values.append(team_values)
```

You were not "resetting" the contents of `team_values` after using it for appending to `teams_values`.

PS: By the time I posted this answer, none of the other two pointed to this "resetting".

Answer (score 1):

```
teams_values = []
for team in team_rows:
    team_data = team.find_all("td")
    team_values = []
    for data in team_data:
        if hasattr(data, 'attrs') and 'data-val' in data.attrs:
            #print("\t{}".format(data.attrs['data-val']))
            value = data.attrs['data-val']
            #print(value)
            team_values.append(value)
            #print(team_values)
    teams_values.append(team_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it only takes a tiny change in your loop logic:

```
teams_values = []
for team in team_rows:
    team_data = team.find_all("td")
    team_values = []
    for data in team_data:
        if hasattr(data, 'attrs') and 'data-val' in data.attrs:
            #print("\t{}".format(data.attrs['data-val']))
            value = data.attrs['data-val']
            #print(value)
            team_values.append(value)
            #print(team_values)
    teams_values.append(team_values)
print teams_values # should show what you want
```